# Velocity.js' very low performance

Tags: javascript, animation, velocity.js

I just changed the animation engine for one of the websites I'm currently working on from Jquery Transit to Velocity.js. I simply changed transition() to velocity() and while it is working, the animations rendered by Velocity.js perform much worse (than Transit's). With Transit I get almost perfect 60fps and correct timing, while Velocity gives me less than 10 fps and the animation speed seems to be incorrect. Velocity's animations give an impression of being heavy and sluggish in comparison to Transit, but in theory Velocity should perform better.

Does anybody have an idea what the problem could be? Could it be that it conflicts with slick.js (carousel), which is also present on that site?

Here's an excerpt of the syntax I use, nothing out of the ordinary, I think.

```
$contactOverlay.velocity({ height: '100%' }, 300);
```

Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Can you provide more code? your html and the rest of the related js? A fiddle would be ideal.

Answer (score 0):

Velocity.js doesn't perform well if it's used together with other Animation-Libraries, like jQuery's animations (especially when they are active at the same time). Make sure Velocity.js is the only thing that is animating elements on your page.
In my experience, pure CSS-Animations shouldn't be a problem, though.